# Error when binding a thread pointer to an object

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I'm doing in C++ something similar to this:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> thread_pointer;
Class myClass {

   // ......
   thread_pointer my_ptr;
}

myClass::function1 {
   my_ptr = new boost::thread(&myClass::function2, this);
}
```

but it says that there is no match for operator '='. I get an error even if I use boost::bind.

Comment: Sharing a thread between multiple instances of `Class` when it was instantiated with the `this` pointer of only *one* of those instances is smelly. Are you sure you mean to share ownership?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor is explicit, so you need

```
my_ptr = thread_pointer(new boost::thread(&myClass::function2, this));
```

or

```
my_ptr.reset(new boost::thread(&myClass::function2, this));
```

This is assuming you need a pointer in the first place.